# java inner classes method access

Tags: java

I have an outer class. I also have a private inner class that extends JPanel. This is the design of the code.

```
public class Outer{
    private class Inner extends JPanel{
        public void doSomeWork(){}
    }

    public Outer(){
        Inner inner = new Inner();
        inner.doSomeWork();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Outer outer = new Outer();
    }
}
```

I am not being able to access the doSomeWork() method of the inner class from the outer class. Please help.

Comment: What do you mean you can't access the method? Are you seeing a compiler error message? If so, please post it here in your question.

Comment: [This compiles just fine](http://ideone.com/G9SCSB).

Comment: Outer outer = new Outer();
Outer.Inner inner = outer.new Inner();
inner.doSomeWork();

Comment: Yep, your code compiles fine. You are not telling us what problem you may be having. Please explain the details. Any edits should be edits to your original question, not a comment.

Comment: I tried it by just putting some Sop in doSomeWork() method. It is working fine and accessable as it is giving out put of Sop.

Answer (score 12):

Here is how you make an object of inner and access its variables...

```
Outer outer = new Outer(); 
Outer.Inner inner = outer.new Inner(); 
inner.doSomeWork();
```

[Example code from Oracle is here...](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/examples/ShadowTest.java)

Comment: This code doesn't work, the inner class is private, so any client code will not be able to access it. But I don't think this is the OP's question, as he seems to be trying to access the inner class from the outer class, not externally.

Comment: How you can say this? I tried by just removing JPanel it is working fine.